# How to add elements of tensor as scalar summaries in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have tensor of 10 elements. How can I add each element as scalar summary, preferably displayed on the same graph in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can access them as if the tensor were a numpy array: `tensor[i,j]`, where the i and j are the indiceswhere the element is located (`tensor[i]` in the case the elemnt is a vector).

Then add them to the summary:

```
for i in tensor:
    tf.summary.scalar("tensor"+ str(i), tensor[i], collections= "tensor")
```

Merge them: `merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all(key=['tensor'])`
Run it: `merged = sess.run(merged_summary, feed_dict={...})` and write it to file writer: `writer.add_summary(merged, epoch)`.

To be able to merge them in the same graph I only know one way which brakes the last merging: using different file writers for each value in the tensor. Nevertheless, the following links could be useful:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-plot-training-and-validation-loss-on-the-same-graph-using-TensorFlow%E2%80%99s-TensorBoard

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7089

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/300

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/664

Comment: doen't work - `iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.`